# How to integrate Umbraco with Microsoft Azure Reseller Web Application?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, umbraco, azure-web-app-service

I have downloaded Reseller Web Application form Partner Center of Microsoft Azure.

https://github.com/PartnerCenterSamples/Reseller-Web-Application

When open the application in Visual Studio, I tried to install Umbraco via Nuget. After installed Umbraco, I run the application in Chrome Browser:

[image]

After install successful Umbraco, I tried to view front end of the web application. But I can only see the front end of Umbraco site but not the front-end of Reseller Web Application from Microsoft Azure.

How can set up my web application to view Reseller Web App's front end as default front end?

*Note: I am using Umbraco 7.5.2*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to [install Umbraco into an empty Asp.Net project](https://our.umbraco.org/documentation/Getting-Started/Setup/Install/install-umbraco-with-nuget). If we deploy the project to Azure, we can deploy Reseller Web App to the root application, and deploy Umbraco to Azure Web app virtual directory. Refer to [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/tomholl/2014/09/21/deploying-multiple-virtual-directories-to-a-single-azure-website/) to know how to deploy multiple virtual directories to a single Azure Website.